# Is Gmail message id incremental?

Tags: api, google-api

I'm using Google API to access Gmail and it is working fine. I will be polling Gmail with date filter in certain intervals to get mails. Can I use messsage ID in validation like 
If received message ID is lesser than the last message ID stored previously then assume it as already processed?

Comment: Sorry its a dump question . The messagei id is not an integer sequence its a hash value so it cant be validated as mentioned